# Setting tab icon image from url

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-imageview

I have an application that has a set of tabs with images set as the TabIndecator. I want to take an image from a URL and set the TabIndecator image as the URL that is specified for that particular tab. Is there a way to do so? Can I take a ImageView and set it as the TabIndecator?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to take an image from a URL and set the TabIndecator image as the URL that is specified for that particular tab. Is there a way to do so?

Not directly, you have to download the image to the device as a `Bitmap`, wrap it in a `BitmapDrawable`, and set it with `TabSpect.setIndicator()`

> Can I take a ImageView and set it as the TabIndecator?

Sure, `TabSpec.setIndicator()` can take a `View` as an argument if you so choose.

Answer (score 0):

This method will allow you to get a local Bitmap from image's URL. My comments are in Spanish but I hope this example will be useful anyway. Make sure to run it in a AsyncTask or similar (not on UI Thread):

```
private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024;
private static final int MINIMO_TAM = 10;
public static final int MAXIMO_TAM = 640;

public static Bitmap loadRemoteImage(CharSequence urlImagen) {
    if (null == urlImagen) {
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap bm = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.addRequestInterceptor(new GzipHttpRequestInterceptor());
    httpclient.addResponseInterceptor(new GzipHttpResponseInterceptor());

    try {
        String urlSinEspacios = urlImagen.toString().replace(" ", "+");

        // Hacer la llamada
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlSinEspacios);
        HttpEntity entity = httpclient.execute(httpget).getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        //Obtener solo el tamaño
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, null, o);
        try {
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        //Calcular mejor escala
        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > MAXIMO_TAM || o.outWidth > MAXIMO_TAM) {
            scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(MAXIMO_TAM / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        //Descargar el real
        entity = httpclient.execute(httpget).getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
        options.inSampleSize = scale;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, null, options);
        // Finalizado
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        bm = null;
    } finally {
        try {
            bis.close();
            is.close();
            // Finalizado
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    return bm;
}
```

Then, you can use a BitmapDrawable to wrap this Bitmap and use with:

```
tabHost.newTabSpec("TODO").setIndicator("TODO", TODO).setContent(TODO);
```